# updating an object element with find and slice

Tags: javascript

I want to update one property-folderId in an object. The new folderId is going to replace all the folderIds in the documentsId.

Below is data i want to modify. The FolderId needs to change to a new value.

```
const documentsId = ["{id: 73, name: "Testilului", extension: "pdf",     
fileSize: 100, folderId: 26},{id: 73, name: "Testilului", extension: "pdf",     
fileSize: 100, folderId: 26}]
```

Want i tried to do is use find to loop through all the elements with find and then i tried to use slice to change value of the folderId.

```
const newFolderId =20;
const index = documentsId.findIndex(item=>item.folderId === newFolderId)
    return [
      ...documentsId.slice(documentsId.folder.Id,indexx),
      newFolderId,
      ...documentsId.slice(index +1)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply iterate over the array and change each ID with the new value:

```
const documentsId = [{
    id: 73, name: "Testilului", extension: "pdf",     
    fileSize: 100, folderId: 26
},{
    id: 73, name: "Testilului", extension: "pdf",     
    fileSize: 100, folderId: 26
}]

documentsId.forEach(obj => obj.id = 20)
```

Comment: that work. thanks. i tried that previously but i had const data declared but it. Should i clone the documentsId with spread so that is not mutated.

Comment: Should i make it immutable? I followed an online tutorial that said you should make it immutable and that you can use the spread operator [...]

Comment: It depends on you needs. You could just `var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(documentsId))` if you need to deep clone it in your case.